# elasticsearch weighted random distribution

Tags: elasticsearch, probability

I want to realize weighted random distribution in elastic search. In my index each document has weight from 1 to N. So element with weight 1 must appears in result 2 times less, than document with weight 2. 
For example I have 3 documents (one with weight 2, two with weight 1):

```
[
            {
                "_index": "we_recommend_on_main",
                "_type": "we_recommend_on_main",
                "_id": "5-0",
                "_score": 1.1245852,
                "_source": {
                    "id_map_placement": 6151,
                    "image": "/upload/banner1",
                    "weight": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "we_recommend_on_main",
                "_type": "we_recommend_on_main",
                "_id": "8-0",
                "_score": 0.14477867,
                "_source": {
                    "id_map_placement": 6151,
                    "image": "/upload/banner1",
                    "weight": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "we_recommend_on_main",
                "_type": "we_recommend_on_main",
                "_id": "8-1",
                "_score": 0.0837487,
                "_source": {
                    "id_map_placement": 6151,
                    "image": "/upload/banner2",
                    "weight": 1
                }
            }
        ]
```

I found the solution with search like this:

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "random_score": {}
                },
                {
                    "field_value_factor": {
                        "field": "weight",
                        "modifier": "none",
                        "missing": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "multiply",
            "boost_mode": "replace"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

After i tested this query with 10000 times result is

```
{
        "5-0": 6730,
        "8-1": 1613,
        "8-0": 1657
    }
```

But not

```
{
        "5-0": 5000,
        "8-1": 2500,
        "8-0": 2500
    }
```

as I expected. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem here is - that your assumption about this distribution - is wrong. We have a classic probabilistic theory problem here. Variables A, B, C uniformly distributed (A, B between 0 and 1, C between 0 and 2). We need to find the probability that C will be greater than either A or B.

Explanation: since C is distributed between 0 and 2 uniformly, by the simple formula it's clear that with **50%** probability it's distributed between 1 and 2 which **automatically** means that it will be greater than either A or B.

However, there are cases, when C will be less than 1 but still greater than either A or B, which makes probability strictly greater than **50%** and much more than 50%.

2nd part of the distribution - where all 3 variables are between 0 and 1. Probability that C will be greater than either A or B is **1/3**. However, C is distributed here only 50% of the time, which makes this probability - 1/6. Total probability is `1/2 + 1/6 = 4/6` which makes roughly numbers you got with Monte-Carlo simulation

Upd. It’s not possible to achieve expected behaviour, since you have no control over scoring, when you will collect aggregations - like sum of weights. I would recommend to do it in a rescore fashion with first requesting the sum aggregation on the field and later re-using it.

Comment: thank you for explanation. I understood my problem, but I can't find any solution for elasticsearch. I found the isssue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7783#issuecomment-64880008, that was about the same question. But it was closed with note, that adviced my wrong solution.

Comment: What kind of solution you want?

Comment: I want make query that returns result with probability = (doc['weight']/sum_of_all_document_weights). For example documents:
{id: 1, weight: 2}
{id: 2, weight: 1}
{id: 3, weight: 1}
So probability of 1 = %50, 2 = 25%, 3 = 25%

Comment: Updated the answer, this is as much as we could go